# how to print file name, creation date and modified date in mac?

Tags: macos, shell

I have a number of folders that contain files. I would like to write them into a CSV file in the following way, for each folder, I look for the files then: file_name, creation_date, modified_date.

Here is my code:

```
DIRECTORY=/root/directory/*
FILES=/Path/to/Files/in_current_directory/*
for d in $DIRECTORY ; do
    for f in $FILES do
    echo "Processing $f" #what is the command for create date and modified date#
    # take action on each file. store current line in a csv file
done
```

How can I change this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your filesystem store creation date?

Comment: Yes, obviously when using GetFileInfo does it. It looks like I should do this in other language may be... could be easier....